# Loading External Jar Files with Java

Tags: java, file, jar, io, runtime-error

I'm trying to run a Jar file with this function, but, it ends up saying it can't

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication2\dist\JavaApplication2.jar":
>   CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Is there any other solution that can fit into this function? I'd like to do this externally through a String, I've explored other solutions, but, have found none that work for me.

```
    private static void runprogram(String path) {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec(path);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Recap.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is `path` value and what is full command that you use to run jar?

Comment: You can't exec the jar file directly, you need to exec java.exe and pass it the relevant parameters to run the jar (i.e. do the equivalent of the command "java -jar yourjarfile.jar")

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work since

> "C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication2\dist\JavaApplication2.jar"

is not a valid program to be run..
You should call (or pass as a`path` argument) this:

> java -jar C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication2\dist\JavaApplication2.jar

Comment: I don't understand your answer, could you rephrase that?

Comment: Your IOException states you were trying to run "C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication2\dist\JavaApplication2.jar".
It looks like it was the **path** argument passed to your **runprogram()** method it's not a program to be run.
The program to be run should be: "java -jar C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication2\dist\JavaApplication2.jar".
Therefore you should run the method with **path** = "java -jar C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication2\dist\JavaApplication2.jar"